# Could some one help me to solve this error am new to Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jar

1.POJO Class
2.Mapping file 
3.configuration file
4.Client APP
5.Jar Files
6.Error

1.POJO CLASS- Employee.java

```
public class Employee {
 private int eno;
private String ename;
private float esal;
private String eaddr;
public int getEno() {
    return eno;
}
public void setEno(int eno) {
    this.eno = eno;
}
public String getEname() {
    return ename;
}
public void setEname(String ename) {
    this.ename = ename;
}
public float getEsal() {
    return esal;
}
public void setEsal(float esal) {
    this.esal = esal;
}
public String getEaddr() {
    return eaddr;
}
public void setEaddr(String eaddr) {
    this.eaddr = eaddr;
}
}
```

2.Mapping file-Employee.hbm.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
     "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

        <hibernate-mapping>
       <class name="com.durgasoft.hbn.pojo.Employee" table="emp1">
         <id name="eno" column="eno"/>
         <property name="ename"/>
         <property name="esal"/>
          <property name="eaddr"/>
         </class>

         </hibernate-mapping>
```

3.Configuration file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

     <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
     "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

     <hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory>
        <property 
         name="connection.driver_Class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
       <property 
        name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin;@1521:demodb</property>
         <property name="connection.username">system</property>
          <property name="connection.password">durga</property>
             <property 
     name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
       <mapping resource="com/durgasoft/hbn/mappings/Employee.hbm.xml"/> 
        </session-factory>
      </hibernate-configuration>
```

4.Client APP-ClientApp.java

```
   package com.durgasoft.hbn.test;

    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
     import org.hibernate.Transaction;
     import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
     import org.hibernate.classic.Session;

      import com.durgasoft.hbn.pojo.Employee;

    public class ClientApp {

       public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {


           Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
      cfg.configure("/com/durgasoft/hbn/cfgs/hibernate.cfg.xml");
      SessionFactory session_Factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
      Session session = session_Factory.openSession();
       Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Employee emp = new Employee();
           emp.setEno(111);
         emp.setEname("AAA");
         emp.setEsal(5000);
        emp.setEaddr("Hyd");

       session.save(emp);
         tx.commit();
        System.out.println("Employee Record inserted succesfully");
        session.close();
           session_Factory.close();
         }

            }
```

5.jar files
Hibernate jar files-
i)hibernate3.jar
ii)antlr-2.7.6.jar
iii)commons-collections-3.1.jar
iv)dom4j-1.6.1.jar
v)javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
vi)jta-1.1.jar
vii)slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
viii)hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
Oracle JDBC Drivers:-
i)ojdbc7.jar
I)slf4j-simple-1.6.1-sources.jar

6.ERROR-

```
   SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
  SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further 
   details.
  Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: 
   Cannot open connection
         at 
  org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException
              (SQLStateConverter.java:140)
       at 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
at com.durgasoft.hbn.test.ClientApp.main(ClientApp.java:20)
  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:453)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
... 5 more
```

**Could some one help me to Solve this Errors (Iam new to hibernate)**

---

Comment: Error is *"Invalid Oracle URL specified"*. The URL you specified is `jdbc:oracle:thin;@1521:demodb` and has nothing whatsoever to do with Hibernate. For one, change the semi-colon (;) to a colon (:), but you're also missing the server name. You should re-read the Oracle JDBC instructions on how the URL should be. The [example in the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm#BEIDHCBA) is `jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@//myhost:1521/myservicename`

Comment: and dont tag this as JPA. You are NOT using the JPA API.

Answer (score 0):

This error mean your app cannot connect to the host URL because the url wasn't understandable. Try this  name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:demodb in your 3rd file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a semi-colon, check few sample urls online.

I guess it should be

```
OLD: jdbc:oracle:thin;@1521:demodb
NEW: jdbc:oracle:thin:@1521:demodb
```